# Create Node Js Executable App for Mac

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack application running on my local laptop. I want to make an executable out of it which I can give to my other teammates so that they can install it on their laptop. My teammates will have mongoDB installed since my app is using mongodb. How can I create such an app. It would be great if while installing the app, it also installs node, express npm on one's laptop.
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). You don't need to use BrowserWindow if you don't need a GUI but Electron gives you nice tools to package and install your app on Mac, Windows and Linux.

Using Electron you could even make the frontend side of your app appear inside of a native window so that no web browser would be needed to access your application.

See:

- http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/

Other options:

- https://jaredallard.me/nexe/
- http://enclosejs.com/

Comment: Thank you! I will try these options.